# String.removingPercentEncoding returns nil on particularly large strings

Tags: ios, swift, string, encoding, urlencode

I am building an application that shows events that are near to the user. Some of these events are scraped from the web, and some are posted to my backend from users of the app. The ones that have been posted to the backend by users are returned with a `description` string property that is URL percent encoded (this has to do with storing emojis in my SQL database, and is a whole other story).

When the events are pulled from my API, some events **will** have percent encoding while others **will not**. Typically, when using `String.removingPercentEncoding` on a string that isn't encoded, nothing in the string changes.

Example:

```
let example = "This is an example text"
let decodedExample = example.removingPercentEncoding!
print(decodedExample)
```

The above code returns `This is an example text`.

Now, with particularly long event description strings that **do not** have percent encoding, we use the same method and expect that it would just return the same string. What I am finding however, is that calling `.removingPercentEncoding` on one of these very long strings is actually returning `nil`. The string in the following example has 3,123 characters.

Example:

```
print("Encoded event description: ", event.description!)
print("Decoded event description: ", self.event.description.removingPercentEncoding ?? "Decoding failed")
```

The above code returns:

```
Encoded event description:  The Experience:\nThe Pavel Barber Hockey School is coming to St. Louis May 17th - 19th, 2019! Join head instructor Pavel Barber, a world renown stickhandling and shootout specialist, and friends for an experience that will challenge these young athletes to get better and encourage mental and physical skill development in a fun and creative environment. \nThe Features:\n\n\n4 Hours On-Ice Skill Development: 1 Hour Friday, 2 Hours Saturday, 1 Hour Sunday\n\n\n4 Hours Off-Ice Skill Development w/ Our Floorball+ HKY Training Program: 1 Hour Friday, 2 Hours Saturday, 1 Hour Sunday\n\n\n1 Personal Growth Group Session Saturday and Sunday\n\n\nScrimmage Game on Sunday\n\n\nPavel Barber Jersey and Socks Included\n\n\nLunch Included Saturday and Sunday\n\n\n \nThe Schedule:Friday, May 17th, 2019 - Day 1 - 5:30 pm - 8 pmSaturday, May 18th, 2019 - Day 2 - 7:30 am - 2 pmSunday, May 19th, 2019 - Day 3 - 7:30 am - 12:30 pm*Times and location subject to change. \n \nOther School Info:\n\n\nSpace is limited and will be filled on a first come, first serve basis\n\n\nAge groups include 7-10 year olds, 11-12 year olds, 13-15 year olds\n\n\nSkill Level Requirements - Kids should be proficient in the basics of hockey before attending the school\n\n\nRefund Policy: Refunds will only be allowed 30 days prior to the start of the school. All refunds are subject to a 20% cancellation fee.\n\n\nThis is not an overnight camp. All kids will need to be picked up and dropped off daily.\n\n\nPlease send your child with the following items each day of the school: workout clothes (such as shorts, t-shirt and gym shoes) for the off-ice sessions and sunscreen as there will be some outdoor activity. Water will be available for the players for all on-ice and off-ice training sessions.\n\n\nPavel Barber and Floorball Merch will be available at the school as well, but we recommend adding to your order now to ensure sizing and product availability\n\n\n \nAbout Pavel Barber:Pavel Barber has quickly emerged as one of the most sought after stick handling and skill development insturctors in the world. He is an internet hockey legend for his incredible hands, creative shootout moves and dangles and his skill development work. His YouTube channel has over 23 MILLION views on it and growing. Barber specializes in stick handling, shoout moves and creative skill development for both hockey and floorball. In fact, he is obsessed with it. He has studied talent generation across all fields and enjoys passing on that knowledge and training hockey players of all ages and skill levels.\nIn 2016, Barber was selected to the Team Canada National Floorball team that competed in Riga at the World Floorball Championships. \nBarber is a GoPro sponsored athlete and has played Indoor Hockey and Field Hockey for Team Canada between 2010 and 2015.\nOriginally from Toronto, Barber currently resides in Vancouver (or anywhere he can have a stick and puck/ball in his hands).\n\nPrice: $350 – $450\n\nFor more info, click here: https://www.eventbrite.com/e/pavel-barber-hockey-school-st-louis-registration-46948450078?aff=ebdssbdestsearch

Decoded event description:  Decoding failed
```

Any idea why `String.removingPercentEncoding` works on typically lengthed strings, but returns `nil` on very large strings (3,000+ characters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried some millions times with random String of length far more than 3,000, and cannot reproduce the same issue.

Your `event.description!` has a non-escaped percent symbol, which is the reason `removingPercentEncoding` fails.

```
...to a 20% cancellation...
```

The length of the string is irrelevant.

Generally, `removingPercentEncoding` fails when the original String contains non-escaped percent symbols.

You can check it easily:

```
let str = "20%"

print(str.removingPercentEncoding ?? "*fail*") //->*fail*
```

If the original string may contain percent symbols, ***always** applying `removingPercentEncoding`* would not be a good strategy.

Comment: So how would one go about escaping the percent symbol? I figured that since "20%" doesn't decode into any symbol, that it wouldn't cause any issues. I guess that when the program sees a non-escaped percent sign, it then looks at subsequent characters, and if those characters do not decode into a symbol, it fails. And this is remedied by either escaping the sign "20\%" or URL encoding it "20%25"?

Comment: @DavidChopin, you can write your own `removingPercentEncoding` with feature safely keeping non-escaped percent symbol. (Though, some sort of combinations may cause issue.) But usually, a single percent symbol is escaped as `%25` in percent-escaped context.